# Merge back to main branch from newly created branch merges all files?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have my "Main" branch from where I branched and created a new "Release" branch. In release we then checked in a few items, and then we were ready to merge back to the "Main" branch, but when I do this I get a changeset containing ALL FILES, why is that? What am I doing wrong? I am only interested in merging what has changed since the branch obviously.

Comment: Are you 100% certain you're merging the child (release) to the parent (Main)? It's the obvious first question...

Comment: Did you rename or move the release branch after it was created?

Comment: @Zelloxy, did you issue solved and is any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

When you merge in Merge wizard in Visual Studio, please choose **Select 
Changesets** not choosing All changes up to a specific version. By default it is at All changes up to a specific version.

Then it list those changsets that haven't merged to the Main branch. You could select the latest changesets to merge.

[image]